# How to show ContentLoadingProgressBar with horizontal indeterminate style

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve horizontal indeterminate style of progress bar with ContentLoadingProgressBar. Below is the xml layout

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbar_Cloud"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

The progress bar is displayed as empty horizontal line with no progress.
By setting

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

Circular indeterminate progress is shown fine. What am I missing, I have even tried

```
ContentLoadingProgressBar bar = (ContentLoadingProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbar_Cloud);
bar.setActivated(true);
bar.show();
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but in case someone else winds up here with the same problem:

You just need to add `android:indeterminate="true"` to your xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbar_Cloud"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:visibility="visible" 
                android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

hope that helps!

Update:

For those of you migrating to AndroidX just update your tag to use

```
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
...
android:indeterminate="true"/>
```